# Card element with favoris cannot trigger API call

Tags: next.js

I am really lost with Nextjs. I seem to have understood that I need to use swr but I am not sure that it will work in my case. or even how to make it work.

I have products which have the same component in several pages in my site. On this component, I have a favorites button which must be triggered on all these pages. on click, it must make a POST or DELETE, with a token and the product id.

My component looks like this for the moment and of course, postFavorites and deleteFavoris don't work:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import Link from 'next/link'
import Styles from "./card.module.scss"
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Card(props) {
  const [favoris, setFavoris] = useState(false);

  const deleteFavoris = async () => {
    console.log("click");
    try {
      const res = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_API}/favorites`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + session.token,
        },
        body: {
          advert: props["@id"]
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        throw new Error(await error.response.data.message)
      }
    }
  }

  const postFavoris = async () => {
    console.log("click");
    try {
      const res = await axios({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_API}/favorites`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + session.token,
        },
        body: {
          advert: props["@id"]
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        throw new Error(await error.response.data.message)
      }
    }
  }
  

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (favoris === true) {
      deleteFavoris()
    } else {
      postFavoris()
    }
    setFavoris(!favoris)
  }


  return (
    <div className={Styles.card}>
      <Link href={"/annonce?id="+props.id} passHref>
        <a className={Styles.imageCard}  style={{backgroundImage: `url(${props.imageSrc})`}}>
          <p className={Styles.localisationCard}><span className="material-icons">location_on</span>{props.localisation}</p>
        </a>
      </Link>
      <div className={Styles.favCard + " " + ((favoris === true) && Styles.active)} onClick={() => handleClick()}></div>
      <p className={Styles.titleCard}>{props.title}</p>
      <p className={Styles.pricesCard}><span className="material-icons-outlined">local_offer</span>Prix : {props.prices}</p>
      <p className={Styles.eligibilitesCard}><span className="material-icons-outlined">check_circle</span>Eligibilité ({props.eligibilities})</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi, not an expert, but I use fetch in my next.js projects and they look like this: 
`fetch('/api/save',{method: 'POST'}, body: data)`
what I mean by this is that if the API folder is inside pages, Next.js will redirect the route to the right place.

Comment: I meant: `fetch('/api/save',{method: 'POST', body: data})`

Comment: _"postFavorites and deleteFavoris don't work"_ - Can you be more specific, what isn't working? Do you get any errors in the console or network tab in the devtools?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @juliomalvesThere is nothing, my fetch actions is not launched. nothing in console or network tab.